# Calculating sigma from a probability distribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

I think this is a rather basic question, but I am not sure if there is already a function in *Mathematica* to do what I need or if I have to write the code myself.

I have this simple code that gives me the probability corresponding to any number of sigma in a normal distribution:

```
Manipulate[
 Probability[μ - n*σ < x < μ + n*σ, x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[μ, σ]], 
 {n, 1, 5}]
```

I would like to know how to do the inverse, that is getting the number of sigma corresponding to a given probability.

Thanks

Comment: How about `Sqrt[2] InverseErf[p]`

Comment: Then you should specify, how this probability is given? It is unclear. I can imagine that you might gave a distribution of points `P(x)` obtained from experiment. Is it the case? Then it is one scenario. You might have a plot of a probability drawn by somebody else with unknown parameters. It is another one. May be something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can come up with the answer given by @SimonWoods using [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html) or [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html). For example:

```
Reduce[
  Probability[ μ - n σ < x < μ + n σ, x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[ μ,σ]] == prob &&
  0 <= prob <= 1 && n > 0, n, Reals
]
```

> 0 < prob < 1 && n == Sqrt[2] InverseErf[prob]

### Update

You may also have used [`InverseCDF`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseCDF.html), since the Normal-PDF is a symmetric function we know:

\begin{align*}
Pr(X\le \mu-n \sigma) &= \Phi(\mu-n \sigma)= \frac{1-p}{2}\\
\Rightarrow  \mu-n \sigma &=\Phi^{-1}\left(\frac{1-p}{2}\right)
\end{align*}

So we do:

```
InverseCDF[ NormalDistribution[μ,σ], (1-prob)/2 ]//Simplify
```

> ConditionalExpression[ μ - Sqrt[2] σ InverseErfc[ 1-prob ], -1<=prob<=1 ]

From this we immediately see that `n = Sqrt[2] InverseErfc[ 1 - prob ]` where `InverseErfc[1-prob]` is equivalent to `InverseErf[ prob ]`.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `Variance`, even for a symbolic distribution, for instance:

```
Variance[MeixnerDistribution[a, b, m, d]]
```

(* 1/2 a^2 d Sec[b/2]^2 *)

and then take the square root.

If you want to get the probability from a threshold try this:

```
Module[{a,x,σ},
 Manipulate[a=N[θ/((4*σ))];
  Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[0,σ],x],{x,-6,6},
  ColorFunction->Function[x,If[Abs[x]>θ,Red,Green]],
  ColorFunctionScaling->False,
  Filling->Axis,
  PlotRange->{{-6,6},{-0.01,0.45}},
  PlotPoints->100,
  Ticks->{
   Union[{{-4*σ,"μ-4σ"},{-3*σ,"μ-3σ"},{-2*σ,"μ-2σ"},{-σ,"μ-σ"},{0,"μ"},{1*σ,"μ+σ"},{2*σ,"μ+2σ"},{3*σ,"μ+3σ"},{4*σ,"μ+4σ"}},{{θ,
   Text[Style[("" """")┬θ,16,Red]],{0.6,0.01},
   Directive[Red,Dashed]},{-θ,
   Text[Style[("" """")┬("-""θ"),16,Red]],{0.6,0.01},
   Directive[Red,Dashed]}}],None}],{{θ,1},0,4},{{a,1,"θ/σ"}},{{σ,1,"σ"},5,1,-0.1}]]
```